# convert getSampleModel to SinglePixelPackedSampleModel

Tags: java

i want to execute this code in java but i face with this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.awt.image.PixelInterleavedSampleModel cannot be cast to java.awt.image.SinglePixelPackedSampleModel
```

can anyone help me?

the source code is :

```
    BufferedImage cat = ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\11.jpg"));
    WritableRaster img=cat.getRaster();
    final SinglePixelPackedSampleModel sppsm;
    sppsm = (SinglePixelPackedSampleModel) img.getSampleModel();
    final int scan = sppsm.getScanlineStride();
```

Answer (score 1):

`img.getSampleModel()` return a `java.awt.image.PixelInterleavedSampleModel` not a `SinglePixelPackedSampleModel`. So you have to change your code:

```
BufferedImage cat = ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\11.jpg"));
WritableRaster img=cat.getRaster();
final PixelInterleavedSampleModel sppsm;
sppsm = (PixelInterleavedSampleModel) img.getSampleModel();
final int scan = sppsm.getScanlineStride();
```